# Decoding failed: Syntax error in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1394 when saving a product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, save

**Magento 1.9**

I am getting this error when I try saving a product. I checked line 1394 in Config.php and it looks like this:

```
$obj = new $className($constructArguments);
```

The full error is:

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception: Decoding failed: Syntax error in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1394
Stack trace:
#0 /app/Mage.php(532): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'Decoding failed...')
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(660): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'Decoding failed...')
```

How can I get more info on what failed or even fix it?

Thanks!